# Azure SQL Server LTR backup notification

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Due to the requirements of ISO accreditation we need to setup notification logic when long term retention backup was taken in Azure SQL Server ( not SQL Server on Azure VM).

Does anyone have any ideas about how to accomplish this goal?

P.S we don’t want to move our DB to Azure VM, so we can’t use Backup Alert service or something like this that is related to SQL Server Azure VM deployment way.

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

There is **no out-of-the-box method to achieve this**. Shortest you can concentrate on is a week [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-backup-retention-configure?tabs=portal#create-long-term-retention-policies).

Below are few points to consider.

You cannot control the LTR backup time, you can define a policy using a combination of four parameters: weekly backup retention (W), monthly backup retention (M), yearly backup retention (Y), and week of year (WeekOfYear) but not exact date and time.

[image]

[Azure SQL database backups - responsibility to monitor and fix #11412](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11412)

[image]

### Possible workaround

Since LTR backups store full Database backups, this causes `Metric` **Full backup storage size** to update. You can monitor through custom charts and [set alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring#create-an-alert-rule).

[image]

You can further leverage [Azure Monitoring REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/rest-api-walkthrough#authenticating-azure-monitor-requests)

Comment: Hi @KarthikBhyresh-MT. Thanks a lot, I will try the workaround you suggest tomorrow and let you know if it will work.

Comment: Sure, ✌ you can also [share an Idea](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0?q=ltr&page=1&sort=relevance&f=04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) or [log an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new) to get an official response too

Comment: Hi @KarthikBhyresh-MT
Could you please tell how you find this metric? I just checked my Metric page in SQL Database and I cannot find any mentions about backup related metric

Comment: the metric is `Full backup storage size` I have just typed `backup` to filter the drop down entries.